# How to make the Discord bot send a message every 24 hours (weekends X)

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am a Discord bot developer. I tried a code that sends a message to a specific channel every 24 hours (weekends X). but it doesn't work :( help me!

````
const client = new Discord.Client();
client.on("ready", () => {
  console.log("Online!");
});
var now = new Date();
var hour = now.getUTCHours();
var minute = now.getUTCMinutes();
client.on("message", (message) => {
  if (hour === 10 && minute === 30) {
    client.channels.get("ChannelID").send("자가진단 하세용!");
  }
});```
````

Answer (score -2):

You can use different types of timers in js
like `setTimeout` or `setInterval` like this:

```
setInterval(() => {
        // your sending message code
    }, 24*60*60*1000);
```

Comment: How do I put it?

Comment: `setInterval` is a function that runs every 24 hour, you just need to send the message inside of it and you dont need to use any other kind of timer or you dont need to check the time inside this function